# ¿Como comparar dos objetos y añadir una nueva propiedad cuando el valor de estos objetos coincidan en JS?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola todos de ante mano muchas gracias.

Estoy intentando comparar dos arrays de objetos, lo que quiero lograr es que si la propiedad id coincide en ambos objetos agregar a mi primer array de objetos un nuevo elemento "selected" con la propiedad true, ya tengo algo armado y funciona más sin embargo no siento que sea la mejor forma ya que al realizar un console.log en el recorrido del forEach veo que se iteran los elementos más veces de lo que se debería.

Comparto mi código para hacerme entender mejor:

Mi primer array:

```
optionsSelect = [
  { id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc" },
  { id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name" },
  { id:16, isActive:true, name:"curp", value:"curp" }
];
```

Mi segundo array:

```
templateSettings = [ 
  { id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc"},
  { id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name"}
];
```

Mi solución:

```js
optionsSelect = [
  { id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc" },
  { id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name" },
  { id:16, isActive:true, name:"curp", value:"curp" }
];

templateSettings = [ 
  { id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc"},
  { id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name"}
];

optionsSelect.forEach(element => {
    templateSettings.forEach(item => {
    //console.log("--------------")
    //console.log(item)
    //console.log("--------------")
        if(element.id === item.id) {
            element.selected = true
        }  
    })
})

console.log('resultado optionSelect', optionsSelect)
```

Si des comentan los console.log, verán a lo que me refiero, ¿Alguna forma de optimizar el código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toda vez que encuentra una coincidencia no es necesario seguir iterando. Es decir que el primer array hay que recorrerlo completo una vez, por cada elemento del primer array hay que recorrer el segundo array hasta la coincidencia (si la hay), si usaramos un `for` habría que poner un `break` luego de una coincidencia (con `forEach` no se puede), pero también podemos usar `.some` que itera solo hasta la coincidencia:

```js
const optionsSelect = [{ id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc" },{ id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name" },{ id:16, isActive:true, name:"curp", value:"curp" }];

const templateSettings = [{ id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc"},{ id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name"}];

optionsSelect.forEach(e => templateSettings.some(t=>t.id === e.id) && (e.selected = true));

console.log(optionsSelect);
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! A veces se me olvida que hay otros métodos que pueden funcionar igual, pero simplifican la codificación, `some()` devuelve un booleano y me parece que es mejor opción que `filter()` para usar en condicional.

Comment: Claro al devolver booleano nos ahorramos una comparación en ciertos casos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) en lugar del ciclo. Te devuelve la posición del elemento (cero en adelante), si es que existe en el arreglo, de lo contrario, devuelve `-1`.

```js
optionsSelect = [
  { id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc" },
  { id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name" },
  { id:16, isActive:true, name:"curp", value:"curp" }
];

templateSettings = [ 
  { id:14, isActive:true, name:"rfc", value:"rfc"},
  { id:15, isActive:true, name:"nombre completo", value:"full_name"}
];

optionsSelect.forEach(element => {
    if(templateSettings.findIndex(item => element.id === item.id) >= 0) {
        element.selected = true;
    };
})

console.log('resultado optionSelect', optionsSelect);
```

Supongo que `findIndex()` recorre internamente el arreglo y la única posible optimización es que finaliza al encontrar una coincidencia.